# VBA Autofilter subset contains extra row up top

Tags: autofilter

The macro attempts to filter Sheet "Temp" for one Criteria at a time (PE, AR, DC,FI), and copy column 5 that contains non-duplicate data into another sheet "Detail". Please help me understand two issues. (1) The macro does correct filtering for each of the 4 criteria. However, the filtered list for each of the criteria always contains the first item from the filtered list of the very first criteria "PE". I.e. the filtered list for criteria 2, "AR", contains all items in AR, but starts with the first item in "PE". There's a header row, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. How can I get rid of that first item in all cases except when filtering for "PE" (where it belongs)? (2) I would like to be able to count and store the number of visible rows for each filtered list. I would like to be able to paste each filtered list into another spreadsheet ("Detail"), starting in cell A4. Each consecutive list should start two rows below the list that was just pasted. For example, if the first list contains 16 items, then the next list should start in cell A22 (A4+16+2). For some reason, copiedrows (used to remember number of rows in a filtered list) is correct the first time around (=16), but not the second time (=1?). It looks like q's 1 & 2 are related. Perhaps, if I figure out #1, I can do something about #2. I reviewed exiting posts on Autofiltering, but still feel a bit stuck here. Really appreciate your help!

```
Sub FilterCategories()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim startpos As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim copiedrows(1 To 4) As Long
Dim AG(1 To 4) As String
Dim rng As Range


AG(1) = "PE"
AG(2) = "AR"
AG(3) = "DC" 
AG(4) = "FI"

'Autofilter based on each AG and copy over to 'Detail'. Create temporary 
 sheet for filtering.


 startpos = 4

        For k = LBound(AG) To UBound(AG)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("Temp").Delete
        Sheets("Lookup").AutoFilterMode = False
        Sheets("Lookup").Copy After:=Sheets("Lookup")
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Temp"

        With Sheets("Temp")
        AutoFilterMode = False

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  


                With .Range("A2:E" & LastRow)

                    .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=AG(k)

                    .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5

                    .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy 
Destination:=Sheets("Detail").Range("A" & startpos)

                    copiedrows(k) = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count

                    Debug.Print copiedrows(k)

                    startpos = copiedrows(k) + 6

                    Debug.Print startpos


                End With


          End With

          Next


End Sub
```

Comment: I found a way to fix #1 - by defining the range to include the header and using Offset(1), offsetting the top row when copying. However, the second issue is how to keep pasting each set of filtered results directly after the set that was just pasted remains. Any help appreciated.

Comment: New code has an issue counting cells that have been copied after running autofilter. for some reason, it counts correctly the first time, but only finds one cell the second time.

Comment: This part:
            
            For k = LBound(AG) To UBound(AG)
                    With .Range("A1:E" & LastRow)
                        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=AG(k)
                        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=5
                        .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Detail").Range("A" & startpos)
                        copiedrows = .Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1).Rows.Count
                        startpos = copiedrows + 5
     
                    End With
              Next

Comment: Okay to close this post. I came up with a different way to write code for this problem.